# Int equivalent of string.isempty

Tags: java, string, int

I am hoping this is an easy fix. I am after a way to detect that the user has hit the enter key when prompted for an int value. I know the .isEmpty does not work with values declared as int, what is the best way to get around this?

```
System.out.println("Please enter the first number:");
    user_number1 = input.nextInt();
        if (user_number1.isEmpty){

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way for an `int` to be empty. `input.nextInt()` will not proceed until the user enters a value that is not whitespace. If it's not an `int`, it will throw a `InputMismatchException`. This is documented in the [`Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) Javadoc. You can test if there is an `int` with `Scanner.hasNextInt()` before trying to consume the next token.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the first number:");
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        user_number1 = input.nextInt();
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("not an int: " + input.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Elliott Frisch's answer states, the `.nextInt()` call is just not going to return until an actual number of some sort is entered (or, if something else is submitted by the user, the `InputMismatchException` occurs instead.

One easy alternative is to just.. not call `.nextInt()` then. call `.next()`, check if the resulting String is empty, and if not, turn it into an integer using: `int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(theStringYouGotFromScannerNext);`.

NB1: Java convention states a variable is named 'userNumber1', not 'user_number1'. When in Rome and all that.

NB2: If you want your scanner to read 1 answer every time the user presses enter, call `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");` immediately after `new Scanner`. Out of the box it gives you 1 answer per whitespace which is usually not what you want in the first place.